# Delete 4 ListBox items by selecting one

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I was wondering but I have 4 listboxes and what I was wondering is how would I delete all 4 of the items by just selecting one item?

As you can see here this is the part that deletes the selected item but how would I delete all 4 items in my listbox if I just selected the "seriesName" one.

```
for (int x = lstb_seriesName.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    int a = lstb_seriesName.SelectedIndices[x];
    lstb_seriesName.Items.RemoveAt(a);
}
```

Here's my code for the delete button.

```
private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstb_seriesName.SelectedItems.Count <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You need to select an item to delete first!");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int x = lstb_seriesName.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            int a = lstb_seriesName.SelectedIndices[x];
            lstb_seriesName.Items.RemoveAt(a);
        }

        System.IO.StreamWriter DeleteFileData = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath);
        foreach (var item in lstb_seriesName.Items)
        {
            DeleteFileData.WriteLine(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in lstb_seriesDay.Items)
        {
            DeleteFileData.WriteLine(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in lstb_seriesTime.Items)
        {
            DeleteFileData.WriteLine(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in lstb_seriesActive.Items)
        {
            DeleteFileData.WriteLine(item);
        }
        DeleteFileData.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Program deleted!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is if you can guarantee that they are all in the same order.

In which case you could take the IndexOf(item) and use the index value to delete the other list items by index.

Otherwise, you need some way to link/relate these guys to each other.

**Edit Per Request:**

```
private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstb_seriesName.SelectedItems.Count <= 0)
        MessageBox.Show("You need to select an item to delete first!");
    else
    {
        var indexesToRemove = lstb_seriesName.SelectedIndices;

        foreach(var index in indexesToRemove)
        {
            lstb_seriesName.Items.RemoveAt(index);
            lstb_seriesDay.Items.RemoveAt(index);
            lstb_seriesTime.Items.RemoveAt(index);
            lstb_seriesActive.Items.RemoveAt(index);
        }    

        MessageBox.Show("Program deleted!");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Would there be any chance that you could give an example? I see what you mean but I'm new to C# so I only really learn through visual interpretation. :)